# AWS SDK PHP - Autoload - Linux

Tags: php, wordpress, aws-sdk

I created a Wordpress Plugin to be able to create an instance on AWS.

After fixed my autoloader cause namespace, now it does work both on Linux and Win, but in Linux I still got this error:
*Fatal error: Class 'Aws\EC2\Ec2Client' not found in blablabla*

File structure:

```
root
    vendor
        |-->aws
        |-->composer
        |-->twig
        |-->...
        |-->autoload.php
    index.php
```

In index.php:

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Why I have this problem on Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft operating systems (DOS and Windows) use backslashes "\", UNIX-based operating systems (Linux) use slashes "/".

Use PHP's helper: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to automatically detect the backslashes/slashes.

Comment: Thank you Norbert. Basically I use `require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';` and this code works `$iam = \Aws\Iam\IamClient::factory(
  array(
    'credentials' => array(
      'key'    => KEY,
      'secret' => KEY_SECRET
    ))
);` **BUT** I can't use `$ec2 = \Aws\EC2\Ec2Client::factory( array(
  'key'   =>  KEY,
  'secret'  =>  KEY_SECRET
  'region'   =>  'eu-west-2'
));` I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'Aws\EC2\Ec2Client' not found in /home/blablabla/public_html/mydomain/wp-content/plugins/plugin-aws/plugin-aws.php on line ..

Comment: Ok the only solution I found is using \Aws\Common\Aws::factory and then get the right object (Ec2, s3, ...).

Comment: So did you check of Aws\Ec2 folder actually exists first ?

Comment: yep, folder exists under vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Ec2

Comment: Anyway, I think my solution it's ok because I read over the documentation: "Service builder
A more robust way to connect to <your service> is through the service builder." so `$aws = Aws::factory...` and `$client = $aws->get('ec2');`

Comment: @gmaccario - Well if it works fine, then use it like this.